# Can I run an escript app from rebar3?

Tags: erlang, rebar3

After creating an escript app:

```
$ rebar3 new escript hello
```

Can I run with with rebar3, instead of calling `escriptize` first?

I.e. something like this?

```
$ rebar3 run
```

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do this currently. Even the generated `README.md` says you have to run `_build/default/bin/script_name` after `rebar3 escriptize`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution might be to add a "run" directive to your makefile instead - this way you can call `make run` which does the `escriptize` step and runs the result.

Depending on what you really want to achieve running `./rebar3 shell` might help you - I do this sometimes so I can debug portions of code just by running the required functions.

Finally you could always write a rebar plugin that extends the escriptize step ;) - never done it myself for rebar3 but has to be easier than the old rebar...

Comment: Thanks. Yes, `escriptize` wouldn't be the same, I was thinking something that does the equivalent to running a shell and then calling main immediately.

Comment: There is a pre-existing rebar3 plugin that does sort of what you ask, shouldn't take much to modify it to work with escripts:

https://github.com/tsloughter/rebar3_run